# Populate Dropdown based on location tags

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a database with a column known as `location_tags`, what I am trying to attempt to do is to allow the user to type in their location, the drop-down should only populate with users with matching location tags and not show the ones that don't have the location tags in them. Here is my table.
[image]

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'tutors') 
or die ('Cannot connect to db');

    $result = $conn->query("select id,name,Location_tags from tutor_location");
?>
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" name="location_input" id="location_input">
<select name="locations" id="locations">
    <script> 
        $("#location_input").keydown(function(){
            const location = $("#location_input").val();
            $("#locations").hmlt(''); //reset dropdown
            // do ajax call to get locations
            $.ajax({
                url: 'search.php',  //replace this with your route of the search function
                data: {location}, //pass location as body data
                dataType: 'json' //expect a json response back
                success: function(data) {
                    data.forEach(function(el) { //loop over the json response
                        let option = `<option id=${el.id} value=${el.name}>${el.name}</option>`
                        $("#locations").append(option); //append locations to select dropdown
                    });
                },
                error: function(err) {  //error functions
                    console.log(err);
                    alert("Error")
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
 <select name='id'>
<?php
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                  unset($id, $name);
                  $id = $row['id'];
                  $name = $row['name']; 
                  echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';

}
?>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

and my search.php code:

```
   <?php
function SearchLocations() {
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'tutors') or die ('Cannot connect to db');
    $result = $conn->query("select * from tutor_location where Location_tags LIKE ='%". $_GET['location']."%'");

    $locations = [];

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $locations[] = $row;    

    }

    return json_encode($locations);

}

?>
```

So for example, if a person types in `Mayfair` then only the first person in the database should be shown in the dropdown, the problem i am facing is that all the items is getting displayed and not based on location and it is not showing in the dropdown

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can use `%search string%` for your `Location_tags` column in your query.

Comment: filter data according to dropdown post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can structure your search function in a separate PHP file to have a clean URL route. Note this query will be prone to SQL injections. This is just a general example

e.g.

```
//  search.php
//  GET request
    function SearchLocations() {
        $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'tutors') or die ('Cannot connect to db');
        $result = $conn->query("select id,name,Location_tags from tutor_location where Location_tags='%". $_GET['location']."%'");

        $locations = [];

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $locations[] = $row;            
        }

        return json_encode($locations);

    }
```

Html:

```
<input type="text" name="location_input" id="location_input">
<select name="locations" id="locations">
```

Then in your javascript code:

```
 $("#location_input").keydown(function(){
            const location = $("#location_input").val();
            $("#locations").hmlt(''); //reset dropdown
            // do ajax call to get locations
            $.ajax({
                url: 'search.php',  //replace this with your route of the search function
                data: {location}, //pass location as body data
                dataType: 'json' //expect a json response back
                success: function(data) {
                    data.forEach(function(el) { //loop over the json response
                        let option = `<option id=${el.id} value=${el.name}>${el.name}</option>`
                        $("#locations").append(option); //append locations to select dropdown
                    });
                },
                error: function(err) {  //error functions
                    console.log(err);
                    alert("Error")
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: I would just like to know where should i put the javascript code, in a different file and link it to my index.php or my search.php?

Comment: Put in in the same page as your search input.

Comment: Hi, please see updated question, the code does not seem to run correctly

Comment: I showed the output in the picture above, the last image

Comment: Console log it. And check your network tab, is it showing any errors?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186779/discussion-between-mohammed-ismail-and-adis).

Comment: @MohammedIsmail check chat pls.